# Is this usage of 'curiously' correct?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-usage

I recently used a sentence similar to the following:

> Curiously, do you prefer black?

Some people found it grammatically incorrect. That was a surprise, for I thought it was perfectly okay. Someone even came with an alternative:

> Out of curiosity, do you prefer black?

Is the second sentence actually better? Is there a real difference (bar the number of characters)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Synonyms for *curiously* include *strangely* or *unusually*. As you can see if you try to substitute either of those into your first sentence, this is not the meaning you're after, and the result is somewhat nonsensical:

> *Strangely, do you prefer black?

The second version actually means what you want it to mean, and is the only correct option of the two. Another way to say it would be:

> I'm curious: do you prefer black?